# Datetime to Year + Week in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, typeconverter, week-number, datepart

I am currently trying to turn a Datetime field into a Year + Week field.
what i have is the following

```
    CreateDate
------------------------
2012-08-15 07:22:56.000
2012-11-16 10:10:00.000
2013-01-22 08:47:37.000
2013-01-22 08:55:18.000
2013-01-22 09:00:38.000
2013-01-29 16:26:25.000
```

and i want this

```
 Weekstamp
------------------------
2013-32
2013-33
2013-34
2013-35
2013-36
2013-37
2013-45
```

can anybody Show me how this is done ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
        select (cast(Year(YourDateTimeColumn) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(datepart(wk,YourDateTimeColumn) as varchar(2))) Weekstamp from YourTableName
```

Comment: This looks about right, but I'm getting error: "'Week' (also 'wk') is not a recognized built-in function name." Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the Answers, here is a slightly better Approach that i've found.

```
convert(varchar, year(CreateDate)) + '-' +right('0' + convert(varchar, datepart(iso_week, CreateDAte)),2) as Weekstamp
```